# Tableau - How to replicated calculated dimension in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, view, tableau-desktop

I have a very large Tableau workbook, which takes a very long time to load. I have determined that this is due to some very large calculated fields which I want to replace to improve the load time.

My plan is to have this calculated field replicated on the database level however, I am unsure what the best approach is and was hoping someone can help me.

The calculated field is essentially a large mapping table, which roles up an area (say area 2) to a higher level named area 1. This is several lines of code and unfortunately I am not able share this due to work.

e.g.

```
IF [area_2] = "abc" THEN [area_2]
ELIF [area_2"] = "def" THEN "xyz"
ELIF [area_2"] = "ghi" THEN "mno"
....
....
END
```

My initial idea was to create a view on top of the database table these attributes come from with a IF Statement. However I have come to understand the views cannot be created with PL/SQL If statements.
I have tried to begin learning PL/SQL elements (i.e. Procedures, Packages, Functions), but finding it hard to determine what is the correct option I should go for.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You should be able to use a CASE statement, instead of the IF statement, within your View definition

Comment: Thanks NickW, this seems to work. Just encountered another issue. In the same query I need create Case Statement and give an alias of "Column X". And also create another Case Statement "Column Y" that references "Column X". However, whenever I run this it says "COLUMN X" is an invalid identifier

Comment: You can't reference a calculated column like that. You can either replace the reference to ColX in ColY with the definition of ColX (likely to be messy) or put the initial query (including the definition of ColX) and then query the CTE and add ColY to the query

Answer (score 0):

I think you have three ways to solve your problem

**If a record always have the same value after the calculation**

1. You can store the calculation value: add to your table columns to store the results of the calculation and create a `TRIGGER` in your table that calculate the values after every insert.
2. Create an Materialized View: If your table don't have a high frequency of inserts, you can create a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`, that store the view result after every insert.

Materialized View Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6002.htm

**If a record can change the value after the calculation**

3. Create a view using `CASE WHEN` or `DECODE` if the calculations are simple as your example, if they're not, use a `FUNCTION` that return the value passing your value and params to calculate the value.